# Apache beam dataflow Big query IO without schema

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Is there any way to write unstructured data to a big query table using apache beam dataflow big query io API (i.e without providing schema upfront)

Answer (score 1):

Bigquery needs to know the schema when it creates the table, or when one writes to it. Depending on your situation one may be able to dynamically determine the schema in the pipeline construction code rather than hard coding it.